# Legacy C# and VB Expression Evaluators in Visual Studio 2019 16.5+

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am working with ArcObjects 10.4 in my .NET Project and I need "Use the legacy C# and VB expression evaluators" option to watch variables while debugging. After updating Visual Studio 2019 to version 16.5 there isn't an option to turn it on. It only shows an empty place where this option should be.

[image: Place where missing option should be]

Is there any way to turn it on or am I stuck with VS 2019 16.4?

Comment: That window (Settings - Options - Debugging) looks severely butchered compared to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/general-debugging-options-dialog-box?view=vs-2019). Many options are missing, including this one.

Comment: That's because I filtered it with "legacy".

Comment: I was not referring to your screenshot.

Comment: VS 2017 gives the following warning when enabling this setting (which it has): *The legacy C# and VB expression evaluator is deprecated and will be removed in future versions of Visual Studio. If you have scenarios that require the legacy evaluator please file a detailed issue report at https://aka.ms/dotnet/issues.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found way to turn it on. In CurrentSettings.vssettings file located in "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxxxxxxx\Settings" there is

`<PropertyValue name="UseVBCSLegacyExpressionEvaluator">0</PropertyValue>`

setting it to 1 makes legacy evaluator work again.

---

**UPDATE**

There is an easier way to turn this option on.

1. In Visual Studio export settings using Tools > Import and Export Settings... > Export selected environment settings > Next > Select only Debugging in Options node > Next >  Finish.
2. Edit exported settings file and change

`<PropertyValue name="UseVBCSLegacyExpressionEvaluator">0</PropertyValue>`

to

`<PropertyValue name="UseVBCSLegacyExpressionEvaluator">1</PropertyValue>`

3. Import back settings to Visual Studio using Tools > Import and Export Settings... > Import selected environment settings > Yes, save my current settings > Next > Browse... > Next >  Finish.

Comment: I did this but it didn't work. After I closed and reopened VS, the setting changed back to 0. I changed it without restarting and it still didn't fix my issue.

Comment: I am no longer working on a project which uses this option, so I don't have a way to check if it is working other than seeing if the option changed. I used an updated method from my post, and it worked in the latest Visual Studio 2019 16.10.4.